# How to determine the coordinates for n identical circles placed at equal spacing along an ellipse?

Tags: geometry

Let's say I have $n$ circles of radius $r$ that are spaced with a nearest-neighbor distance of $\delta$. (i.e. the shortest distance between any two particles is $\delta$.)

It is trivial to determine the coordinates ($x_n$,$y_n$) of the centre of these circles if they are placed along a circle. (You can simple use the rotation matrix.) Here is a schematic of these circles placed around a circle:

[image: Circles placed around a circle]

If I want to place these circles around an ellipse of axes $a$ and $b$, how do I determine the coordinates of the centre of each circle? Approximations are OK.

Comment: Your use of “edge-to-edge” confuses me, as you're talking about distances immediately afterwards. What edges? Given the fact that even computing arc lengths for the ellipse requires [elliptic integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral) which cannot be expressed using elementary functions, this sounds like a hard problem. Do you need exact formulas (very likely using unevaluated elliptic integrals), or are numeric approximations acceptable? Also where do you measure $\delta$? On the shortest route connecting circle centers, or along the arc of the ellipse?

Comment: @MvG, just updated my question for clarity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The points on the ellipse satisfy the equation
$$
\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1.
$$
If a small circle is centered at $(x_0,y_0)$, then any neighbor at a distance $\delta$ will have center coordinates satisfying
$$
(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=\delta^2;
$$
if the center is, in addition, constrained to lie on the ellipse, then you have two quadratic equations in the two variables $(x,y)$, which can be solved exactly.  Iterating this procedure (starting at $(a,0)$, for instance) will give the coordinates of successive circle centers on the ellipse.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess it is also important to determine what the lengths $a$ and $b$ have to be in order to have $n$ equally spaced particles along the ellipse.

Comment: This question can help: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72555/57054